# Вопрос про SSKeyChain

Tags: ios

Правильно ли я понимаю, если приложение через эту библиотеку запишет некий ключ-комбинацию в устройство, то даже при переустановке приложения либо очистки кэша, значение ключа сохранится и его можно будет оттуда восстановить (через тоже самое приложение)? Если это так, то можно код-пример?

Хотелось бы при первом запуске приложения сгенерировать комбинацию, записать ее один раз в keychain и иметь доступ к ней из этого приложения всегда, даже после переустановки.

И точно ли на устройстве хранятся эти ключи? Либо это облачное хранилище?

[Ссылка на библиотеку](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain)

Comment: Если бы вы отметили мой ответ как принятый, that would've been great :)

Comment: Алексей, справедливо ли ниже написанное для всех iOS устройств (iPhone, iPad)? И что такое provisioning profile и как избежать его смены? :)

Comment: Да, для всех. Provisioning profile - это подписанный вашим сертификатом файл, где указывается, какими службами пользуется ваш апп, а также опционально каким устройствам его можно запускать (важно при бета-тестировании через сервис вроде TestFlight или fabric.io)

Comment: Если в Provisioning profile добавить / убрать, скажем, планшеты... он останется тем же Provisioning profile?) У андроида я подписывал ключем... видимо оно же.

Comment: Не знаю, не проверял. Я подозреваю, что значение имеет только app ID и сертификат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSKeychain работает со стандартной службой keychain iOS. В отличие от OS X, в iOS связка ключей одна:

> In iOS, the situation is simpler: There is a single keychain
>   accessible to applications. Although it stores the keychain items of
>   all the applications on the system, an application can access only its
>   own keychain items (with the possible exception of a keychain item for
>   which the application that created it obtained a persistent
>   reference).

Поэтому удаление приложения никак не повлияет на содержание связки ключей. Однако если подписать другую версию приложения другим provisioning profile, оно потеряет доступ к своим записям в ней:

> Note: On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile
>   used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same
>   provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

[Документация Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9)

Чтобы убедиться в этом на практике, достаточно написать тестовое приложение с одним текстовым полем и сохранять его значение в keychain:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <SSKeychain.h>

NSString * const kService = @"foo";
NSString * const kAccount = @"bar";

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *secretField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.secretField.text = [SSKeychain passwordForService:kService account:kAccount];
}

- (IBAction)saveSecret:(UITextField *)sender {
    [SSKeychain setPassword:sender.text forService:kService account:kAccount];
}

@end
```